# How to calculate the max number of worker threads in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, cpu, multi-thread

I use 64-bit OS with two CPUs (each of them makes 7 logical processors) and with total number of logical processors equal to 14.

When I run this code I get **2048**

```
SELECT max_workers_count FROM sys.dm_os_sys_info
```

On the other way, when I use the formula below I get totally different number which is **672**

```
For a 64-bit operating system:
Total available logical CPUs <= 4
Max Worker Threads = 512
Total available logical CPUs > 4
Max Worker Threads = 512 + ((logical CPUs - 4)*16)
```

Can you explain to me why I get different numbers? I tested it on another server and got exact same numbers for both cases.

**EDIT**

[image]

P.S Thanks to Dan Guzman for his suggestions to check server settings for max worker threads. That is what EXEC sp_configure 'max worker threads' returns:

[image]

Comment: where did you get that formula ?

Comment: I have 24 logical cores and I get correct result 832.

Comment: @DanGuzman thank you for suggestion to check default settings. It seems that someone changed that value.  The next question came into my mind:  is this value makes any sense if max calculated value can only be 672? In other words, if I set the value to 3000 instead of 2048, will it make any sense as according to formula above max worker thread count is up yo 672?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems someone has changed the maximum worker threads setting to a non-default value, which will override the default calculated value. The current configured value can be determined with:

```
EXEC sp_configure 'max worker threads';
```

I'll add the value is sometimes set mistakenly as a knee-jerk reaction to address symptoms rather than the underlying cause. Some valid reasons for configuring the value are called out in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-max-worker-threads-server-configuration-option) but the default calculation is appropriate for most workloads.

Comment: Can it happen that SQL Server uses those 2048 threads? I wonder whether it will use up to 672 or will cross the line and use over 672.

Comment: @RaufDBA, the `max_workers_count` is the limit regardless of whether it was configured manually or automatically.

Comment: Thank you. Now it is clear

Comment: What happens when the max limit has reached and a new query arrives?

Comment: @variable, when no worker threads are available. those tasks encounter `THEADPOOL` waits until a worker is available.

Comment: Is there any limit to the amount of time the query (request/task) will wait for a worker thread?

Comment: @variable, timeouts are controlled by the client application via a command or connection timeout specification. The database engine does not limit the time.

Answer (score 2):

The formula works for me, I have 32 logical cores, 512+((32-4)*16) = 960 which is exactly what I get from

```
SELECT max_workers_count FROM sys.dm_os_sys_info
```

Could you go into Task Manager -> Performance Tab -> CPU, and post here a screenshot of basic CPU information from your system (sockets, cores, logical processors, etc) ?

Comment: Sure. I've added